# How to display the Current Month in Plain Text Format?

Tags: windows, powershell, keyboard-shortcuts, plaintext

Any suggestions on how I can quickly print the **current month** of a calendar in plain text to the clipboard or to the command in the a windows environment? To be clear here, I would like to see the full printed month, similar to what you see when you single click on the clock in the windows taskbar. I'm thinking along the lines of a a lightweight PowerShell script or perhaps there is some other pre-packaged Windows application functionality that would allow me to do this easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
function Get-Calendar($year=(Get-Date).Year,$month=(Get-Date).Month){
    $dtfi = New-Object System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo
    $AbbreviatedDayNames=$dtfi.AbbreviatedDayNames | ForEach-Object {" {0}" -f $_.Substring(0,2)}

    $header= "$($dtfi.MonthNames[$month-1]) $year"
    $header=(" "*([math]::abs(21-$header.length) / 2))+$header
    $header+=(" "*(21-$header.length))

    Write-Host $header -BackgroundColor yellow -ForegroundColor black
    Write-Host (-join $AbbreviatedDayNames) -BackgroundColor cyan -ForegroundColor black
    $daysInMonth=[DateTime]::DaysInMonth($year,$month)

    $dayOfWeek =(New-Object DateTime $year,$month,1).dayOfWeek.value__
    $today=(Get-Date).Day

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $dayOfWeek; $i++){Write-Host (" "*3) -NoNewline}
    for ($i = 1; $i -le $daysInMonth; $i++)
    {
        if($today -eq $i){Write-Host ("{0,3}" -f $i) -NoNewline -BackgroundColor red -ForegroundColor white}
        else {Write-Host ("{0,3}" -f $i) -NoNewline -BackgroundColor white -ForegroundColor black}

        if ($dayOfWeek -eq 6) {Write-Host}
        $dayOfWeek = ($dayOfWeek + 1) % 7
    }
    if ($dayOfWeek -ne 0) {Write-Host}
}

PS> Get-Calendar

    January 2013
 Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
        1  2  3  4  5
  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
 27 28 29 30 31
```

Comment: To be clear here, I would like to see the full printed month, similar to what you see when you single click on the clock in the windows taskbar.

Answer (score 1):

A calendar (a system for breaking a linear date into day/month/year) doesn't have a current anything.

But if you mean get the month of a [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime) in a given calendar you need to look at specifying a [`CultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) which in .NET incorporates a selected calendar:

```
$d = Get-Date
$d.ToString('MMMM', [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture)
```

There are a number of ways to create a custom `CultureInfo` or (more generally) an instance of [`DateTimeFormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx) and passing as the second parameter of [`DateTime.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/8tfzyc64).

The simplest approach is to get an instance of `CultureInfo` that uses the target calender, eg.:

```
$ci = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CreatedSpecifiedCulture('jp-jp')
```

MSDN has a whole page on working with calendars: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82aak18x%28v=vs.100%29.aspx (this is the .NET 4 version for PowerShell 3).

Comment: To be clear here, I would like to see the full printed month, similar to what you see when you single click on the clock in the windows taskbar.

Answer (score 1):

```
new-alias  Out-Clipboard $env:SystemRoot\system32\clip.exe
(get-date -Format MMMM) |Out-Clipboard
```